# How to share two private keys ,while anyone else is listening in on the conversation

Tags: encryption, cryptography, private-key

Cryptographic hashing is a very useful concept. The MD varieties are no longer sufficiently secure--you can break them in reasonable time using Amazon cloud. We use SHA-512 for our superuser password.

While we're on cryptography, you should explain how 2 people can share a completely private key while anyone else is listening in on the conversation. That is the basis of all security on the Internet.

Comment: You never share private key, You share only share public key.

Comment: How we can make our conversation more secure using which technique ?

Comment: This probably belongs on [IT Security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/), and may be a duplicate of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43542/totally-secure-public-key-distrubition there.

Comment: Are you talking about symmetric encryption in which data is encrypted/decrypted using same key which you are reffering here as private key. Otherwise @VikasMadhusudana's comment holds.

Comment: As i want to know that we two people are conversing on some chat and sharing our keys and some other person is also in chat. So how can we secure the chat for two people

Comment: So this is how it generally work you share your public key with him he uses  the public key to encrypt a symmetric key and shares it with you. Now you are the only person who can decrypt as you are the only person having private key. so now you both have a symmetric key which you use to encrypt the other messages.

Comment: looks like it has to do with data that you are trying to push http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/JsonParseException-Current-token-END-OBJECT-not-numeric-can-not-use-numeric-value-accessors-td4037985.html

Comment: Is your question revolving around how to avoid main in the middle who has the option to swap the shared public keys with his own, thus being able to sniff the traffic? There's only one option available for that to my limited knowledge, however - you should expand your question with exact issue and not a general one. Personally, I'd authenticate both participants using something like [Yubikey U2F key](https://www.yubico.com/about/background/fido/), which can mitigate against MITM.

Comment: @HarkiratSinghLamba When you say "private key" do you mean the private key of a public/private key pair as used by RSA or do you mean a secret key as used by AES? Note: "private key" has a very specific meaning in cryptography.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about cryptography, not a specific programming problem. Please see the [help/on-topic] and the [ask] page for some help on asking a good question.

Answer (score 2):

> How to share two private keys ,while anyone else is listening in on the conversation

You never share private keys. Why would I listen in on any conversation? You mean *could* listen in on the conversation.

> Cryptographic hashing is a very useful concept.

Yes, and the sun is hot.

> The MD varieties are no longer sufficiently secure--you can break them in reasonable time using Amazon cloud.

MD2 to MD6 are hashes created by Ronald Rivest. There is no such thing as an "MD" variety - other than that it was made by Rivest. If you mean [Merkle-Damgård](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) then that construction is considered secure. There are specific attacks on MD5 and MD6 was withdrawn from the SHA-3 competition. But the statement "you can break them in reasonable time using Amazon cloud" is way too generic.

> We use SHA-512 for our superuser password.

That's a shame, because while SHA-512 is a crytographically secure Merkle-Damgård hash, it is not a *password hash* such as PBKDF2, Bcrypt or Scrypt.

> While we're on cryptography, you should explain how 2 people can share a completely private key while anyone else is listening in on the conversation.

Yes, you'd generally use an (authenticated) Diffie-Hellman construction. Or any other key establishment scheme.

> That is the basis of all security on the Internet.

There is no single "basis of all security" on the internet.

Comment: Had to create an answer, because there is just not room enough in the comments to debunk *each and every line* of the above thing that is supposed to be a programming question.

Comment: how 2 people can share a private key in plain sight? This was basically my question.

Comment: and thnx @Maarten Bodewes for your help.